# Converting ejs to jade?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, ejs

I'm having trouble converting the following ejs to jade:

```
<h1>I’m going to count to <%= counter %></h1>

<p><%
    for(var i = 1 ; i <= counter ; i++) {
    %>

    <%= i %>... 

<% } %></p>

<p>While I’m here, I’m going to take a name at random that’s been sent to me:
<%= names[Math.round(Math.random() * (names.length - 1))] %>
</p>
```

How would this block look in jade? Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
- var counter = 10
- var names = ["Tom", "Dick", "Harry"]
h1 I’m going to count to #{counter}
-
  var countdown = ""
  for (var i = 1 ; i <= counter ; i++){
    countdown += i + "..."
  }
p=countdown
p While I’m here, I’m going to take a name at random that's been sent to me: #{names[Math.round(Math.random() * (names.length - 1))]}
```

In this example I have made counter and names variables within the Jade file, but you can just as easily pass them as values to the template.